# Xcode 9.3 build upload Error: An error occurred saving your changes to the Apple database. (1015)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode9.3

Error in upload builds on TestFlight/AppStore. I am using Xcode 9.3 and error throws:

**An error occurred saving your changes to the Apple database.  This problem may be a transient issue on the Apple side.  If the problem persists for more than an hour, please contact your iTunes representative. (1015)**

Anyone help me why I am getting this error?

[image]

Comment: (27-28 Jun 2018) Got the same error. Have you solve it?

Answer (score 5):

When the error message hints to an error on Apples side, check the status page: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Looks like there was an issue in AppStore Connect API today. It should be fixed now, so you can retry.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issues several times last week. I have couple apps in dev account but the error happened only for one of them.
Haven't found out a cause. Looks like an issue on AppStore Connect.